# Typescript types when iterating layers in Leaflet

Tags: typescript, leaflet

I have a Leaflet map that contains some GeoJSON layers (and other layers besides). I want to iterate over the layers to find the GeoJSON layer with a property matching some target value. The problem I have is getting the type annotations right, such that I don't get warnings from the TypeScript compiler.

The core issue is:

```ts
const map:L.map = ...

map?.eachLayer(layer => {
  // @ts-expect-error GeoJSON layers do have a feature property
  const feature = layer.feature

  if (feature) {
    const layerId = feature.properties['someIdProperty']

      if (layerId === targetId) {
        // @ts-expect-error We know that this layer has bounds
        map?.fitBounds(layer.getBounds())
      }
    }
  })
```

The code does run correctly, but I can't find a way to type the `layer` variable to avoid getting compiler warnings. Hence resorting to the ugly `@ts-expect-error` hack.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the instance of the layer is a `GeoJSON` layer:

```
map?.eachLayer(layer => {
    //GeoJSON layers do have a feature property
    if(layer instanceof L.GeoJSON){
        const feature = layer.feature
        if (feature) {
            const layerId = feature.properties['someIdProperty']
            if (layerId === targetId) {
                map?.fitBounds(layer.getBounds())
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks, that does help. I'm still getting a compiler warning from `feature.properties` though

Comment: Actually, I have to update that comment. This solution makes the type-checker happy (well, happier), but the actual if-condition is failing. Looking at the app in devtools, the layer is actually an instance of `NewClass`, which I assume is some dynamically generated class that the Leaflet loader creates.